# How to install v4l2loopback on Ubuntu 22.04.3?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 22.04, dkms

I am using a release image of the LTS version, and I believe it is up to date as far as `apt update`/`apt upgrade` goes:

```
root@trainwatching:~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS \n \l

root@trainwatching:~# uname -a
Linux trainwatching.vm.somehost.local 5.15.0-1046-kvm #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 17:10:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But I can't install the v4l2loopback kernel module:

```
root@trainwatching:~# apt install v4l2loopback-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  v4l2loopback-dkms
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/29.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 113 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package v4l2loopback-dkms.
(Reading database ... 95390 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../v4l2loopback-dkms_0.12.7-2ubuntu2~22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking v4l2loopback-dkms (0.12.7-2ubuntu2~22.04.1) ...
Setting up v4l2loopback-dkms (0.12.7-2ubuntu2~22.04.1) ...
Loading new v4l2loopback-0.12.7 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-1046-kvm
Building initial module for 5.15.0-1046-kvm
Error! The /var/lib/dkms/v4l2loopback/0.12.7/5.15.0-1046-kvm/x86_64/dkms.conf for module v4l2loopback includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch.
The /var/lib/dkms/v4l2loopback/0.12.7/5.15.0-1046-kvm/x86_64/dkms.conf for module v4l2loopback includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch/config.
This indicates that it should not be built.
Skipped.
```

Shouldn't packages "Just Work" within a stable release? I did find some discussion of a [similar error message](https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/2536#issuecomment-1195735872) but my version of the file already has that fix yet still not working.

Comment: It is similar to this one may be you can debug it, https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/2536 (Pop-OS is a derivative and Launchpad bug report is linked there)

Comment: yes, that is the same issue I linked to in my post — the additional `BUILD_EXCLUSIVE` flags are already in conf file so there is nothing to manually change. plus the upstream bug they linked to is resolved, so shouldn't it be working now?